# C++11 on the fly construction inconsistency

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11 we can now construct objects on the fly in function arguments.

For example, we can insert a new pair into a std::map like so:

```
typedef std::map<char, int> MapType;
MapType my_map;

my_map.insert({'f', 6}); //less verbose than make_pair
```

This also works for std::vector. However, for std::array this strangely does not work.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void arr_on_fly(std::array<int, 4> arr)
{
    /*...*/
}

void vec_on_fly(std::vector<int> vec)
{
    /*...*/
}

int main() 
{
vec_on_fly({1, 2, 3, 4});
arr_on_fly({1, 2, 3, 4});
}
```

Link: http://ideone.com/gvIUF

Why does this not work? Is this a deficiency in the C++11 Standard?

The error "could not convert '{1, 2, 3, 4}' to 'std::array'" seems absurd as we can initialize a std::array like so:

```
std::array<int, 4u> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Comment: You know what, C++03 let's you *construct objects on the fly in function arguments*, too, you just have to use a different syntax ;)

Comment: "*we can initialize a std::array like so: `std::array<int, 4u> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};`*" Right, but you __cannot__ construct one like so: `std::array<int, 4u> arr{1, 2, 3, 4};` -- it must instead be `std::array<int, 4u> arr{{1, 2, 3, 4}};`. The same applies to the context you're trying: `arr_on_fly({{1, 2, 3, 4}});`.

Comment: ildjarn, you are wrong. See http://ideone.com/R3QUn

Comment: @Ricky65 : I'm not wrong, GCC 4.5.x is just defective in this regard. That won't work in e.g. GCC 4.7.

Comment: ildjarn, I have tested it on GCC 4.7 and it compiles and runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the reason for this inconsistency. But adding extra braces makes it compile.

```
arr_on_fly({{1, 2, 3, 4}});
```

Comment: "*I don't know the reason for this inconsistency*" One is "uniform-initialization", the other is aggregate-initialization. Despite an intentional superficial similarity, the syntax rules are different.

Comment: It doesn't compile on Ideone (gcc-4.5.1) with the extra pair of braces. See http://ideone.com/ss4OB.

Comment: @Ricky65 : That's merely a defect in GCC 4.5.x.

Comment: @ildjarn that sounds like you say that one is not aggregate initialization and the other is not done by uniform initialization. But uniform initialization is the global goal of any {...} thing, and both do aggregate initialization when applied to std::array!

Answer (score 0):

The `{}` are overloaded. In balki's solution

```
arr_on_fly({{1, 2, 3, 4}});
```

the outer brackets mean infer-a-constructed-object and the innermost brackets mean construct-an-initializer-list.

To be honest, I'm suprised the call isn't ambiguous in any case. I can't recall the exact rules for the interaction of initializer lists and inferred construcors, but if you add an overload

```
arr_on_fly(std :: initializer_list <int>)
```

then cast it and defer processing to another function, that should work.

Comment: "*the outer brackets mean infer-a-constructed-object and the innermost brackets mean construct-an-initializer-list*" `std::array<>` is an aggregate type, so there is no use of `std::initializer_list<>` here at all; the outer brackets initialize the `std::array<>` while the inner initialize the `std::array<>`'s inner C-array.